# Is $1 - 2x$ invertible $\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Let $1-2x \in \mathbb{Z}[x] \subset \mathbb{Z}[[x]]$?

1. Is $1 - 2x$ invertible $\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$?
2. Is $\bar{1} - \bar{2}x$ invertible $\in \mathbb{Z}_{4}[x]$?
3. true/false: $1-2x \in U(\mathbb{Z}[[x]])$ with $(1-2x)^{-1}$ = $1+2x+4x^2+8x^3+...$

My attempt: 1. and 2. $(a + bx)(1 - 2x) = 1 => a - 2ax + bx - 2bx^2 = 1=> a - 2bx^2 - x(2a - b) = 1$, and if we let, $(2a - b) = 0$, we get, $b = 2a$.
$a - 4ax^2 = 1$ and now I don't know where to go after that.

3. True since $(1-2x)*(1+2x+4x^2+8x^3+...) = 1$

Comment: For part 2, $\overline{1} + \overline{2}x$ is the multiplicative inverse of $\overline{1} - \overline{2}x$ since $(\overline{1} + \overline{2}x)(\overline{1} - \overline{2}x) = \overline{1} - \overline{4}x^{2} = \overline{1} - \overline{0}x^{2} = \overline{1}$.

Comment: But, don't you need to show how did you get it?

Comment: It is written in the comment. Note that $\bar 4=\bar 0$ in $\Bbb Z_4$.

Comment: Well, I looked at $\overline{1} - \overline{2}x$.  I remembered that in $\mathbb{Z}_{4}[x]$, $4$ is the same thing as $0$.  So, I thought, maybe I could multiply $\overline{1} - \overline{2x}$ by something so that the $1$ stays but the $2x$ becomes something with $4$ as the coefficient (since $4$ is $0$).  Well, I remembered that $(a - b)(a + b) = a^{2} - b^{2}$, and it pretty much came to me that $\overline{1} + \overline{2}x$ is the inverse of $\overline{1} - \overline{2}x$.

Comment: By the way, I just want to add that in $\Bbb Z_{4}$, $\overline{-2} = \overline{2}$, so that means $\overline{1} + \overline{2}x = \overline{1} - \overline{2}x$, i.e., $\overline{1} - \overline{2}x$ is its own multiplicative inverse!  You can check this: multiply out $(\overline{1} - \overline{2}x)(\overline{1} - \overline{2}x)$, and you will see it equals $\overline{1}$.

Comment: @abcd1234 Great :)

Comment: That's what I love about abstract algebra. It's really simple and yet very clever/tricky. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You also have to consider polynomials of higher degree. But, anyway, $(1-2x)\cdot f$ will have even higher degree, so we never get the constant $1$ polynomial.
2. See the comments: $(1+2x)$ is an inverse for $(1-2x)$ as $4=0$ in $\Bbb Z_4$.
3. Yes, it is true now if we allow 'infinite polynomials', i.e. formal power series. Substitute $z=2x$ in the formula for geometric series $\displaystyle\frac1{1-z}=1+z+z^2+z^3+\dots$

Comment: Oops! We were writing almost at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

$1$. It's not invertible in $\mathbf Z[x]$ because  $\mathbf Z$  is an integral domain, so the degree of a non-zero multiple of $1-2x$ is greater than the degree of $1-2x$, hence it can't be of degree $0$.

$2$. It is invertible in $\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z[x]$ and its inverse is $1+2x$: indeed $(1-2x)(1+2x)=1-4x^2=1$ since $4=0$ in $\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for pointing the typo!

Comment: One more question though: Is there any way I can understand something doesn't have a multiplicative inverse?

Comment: @abcd1234 Think about elements of $\Bbb Z$, like $2$, for example.  What is the multiplicative inverse of $2$?  It is $\frac{1}{2}$, but this is not in $\Bbb Z$, so there is no inverse of $2$ in $\Bbb Z$.  Do you understand why $1 - 2x$ has no inverse in $\Bbb Z[x]$?

Comment: Very general question! I'm afraid there's no general answer in practice. Belonging to a maximal ideal and being a zero divisor are two reasons for not being invertible. In rings of integers in number fields, having a norm $>1$ (but that' getting rather technical).

Comment: @abcd1234 If it did have an inverse, we know what the inverse would be.  It would be $\frac{1}{1 - 2x}$.  But there is no way to express this element as a polynomial -- it is a rational function.  So it is not in $\Bbb Z [x]$.

Comment: Hmm. I think I got it now.

Comment: But, as you saw in my comment, in certain places you *can* find inverses **sometimes**, like when we change the coefficients from being in $\Bbb Z$ to being in $\Bbb Z_{4}$, which allowed $1 + 2x$ to be invertible (but this doesn't mean every element of $\Bbb Z_{4}[x]$ is invertible...).  Similarly, in the field of complex numbers $\Bbb C$, what is the inverse of $a + bi$?  Well we know it should be $\frac{1}{a + bi}$.  Is this in $\Bbb C$?  At first you might think "no" since it doesn't look like we can express $\frac{1}{a + bi}$ as $c + di$...

Comment: @abcd1234 BUT, notice that $\frac{1}{a + bi} = \frac{1}{a + bi} \frac{a - bi}{a - bi}$ = $\frac{a - bi}{a^{2} + b^{2}} = \frac{a}{a^{2} + b^{2}} - \frac{b}{a^{2} + b^{2}}i$.  So actually $\frac{1}{a + bi}$ **is** in $\mathbb{C}$!  Since it is expressible as some $c + di$.  This is just to help you get familiar with some cases where there is an inverse when you might not think there is.  But with $\Bbb Z[x]$, as we said, you can't write $\frac{1}{1 + 2x}$ as a polynomial, so the inverse is not in $\Bbb Z[x]$.

Comment: @abcd1234 One last thing I want to say: this argument of "is $\frac{1}{1 + 2x}$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$?" is OK when we are talking about the polynomial ring $\Bbb Z[x]$, but you can't always use it.  For example, you might have said "Well, $\frac{1}{\overline{1} + \overline{2}x}$ isn't in $\Bbb Z_{4}[x]$..." -- but the element was invertible, as we saw.  So, in cases like $\Bbb Z_{n}$, you have to be more clever, as I explained in my comment on how I found the inverse under your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detail explanation. It really makes sense to me.

Comment: @abcd1234 Very good, I'm happy to hear that. :)